# Why the amplifier AB does not amplify the signal?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, signal, proteus

I have this amplifier AB, but when I measure the signal with the digital oscilloscope, it does not amplify anything, (the yellow one is the output signal, and the blue is the Vin), also when I take out the potentiometer or change it's % the signal doesn't change. Does someone know why this happen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not really an entire amplifier. You are talking about a simple output *stage*. This arrangement is intended to provide greater current compliance, not voltage amplification.

Answer (score 3):

It does amplify, but not voltage.

That is simply the output buffer part of an amplifier, not the voltage amplifying part of an amplifier. And the pot is not for changing amplitude, only the bias point of the transistors, and the effect on the output can be very subtle.

Comment: It amplifies current.

Answer (score 1):

Justme is correct.

Another way to look at it is that each transistor is configured as a follower (more or less). Assuming a constant Vbe when conducting, when the NPN is conducting, the output will follow the input. When the PNP is conducting, the output will follow the input. The function of R1/R2/V1 is to make sure that one or the other is always conducting, thereby avoiding what is known as "crossover distortion".